# Why does this code work fine in Google Chrome, but refuses to Safari (and on the Mac and on the iPhone)?

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-chrome, safari

The code helps smoothly lower the user's screen to the anchor, with the necessary indentation from above, so that the menu fixed at the top does not obscure it.

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var target = this.hash,
                $target = $(target);
                $calculus = ( $target.offset().top - 75 );
            $target_to = $calculus.toFixed();
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': ($target_to+'px')
                }, 900, 'swing');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Some browsers don't like you messing with the `<html>` or `<body>` elements like that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution that works on all platforms:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"], *[data-href^="#"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var t = 1000;
        var d = $(this).attr('data-href') ? $(this).attr('data-href') : $(this).attr('href');
        $('html,body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(d).offset().top - 80 }, t);
    });
});
```